# Facebook get href from attachment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get image url from attachment. I have a FQL Query as follows

```
SELECT post_id , message, comments, created_time, attachment 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id=XXXXXXX AND actor_id = XXXXXXXXXX 
       AND created_time >= 1356912000 AND created_time <= 1388448000 
 LIMIT 100000
```

How to extract href, aid, pid, fbid from above query?

Comment: It is ok for `href`, which indeed exists into the stream's attachment structure. But what are `aid`, `pid` and `fbid`? They don't exist in the `stream` table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do `attachment.href`.

```
SELECT post_id , message, comments, created_time, attachment.href
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id=XXXXXXX AND actor_id = XXXXXXXXXX 
       AND created_time >= 1356912000 AND created_time <= 1388448000 
 LIMIT 100000
```